# CSS file filemtime without calling path twice

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylesheet.css?v=<?php filemtime('/css/stylesheet.css') ?>">
```

Calling `/css/stylesheet.css` twice is a bit annoying. Is there any way to do this just by calling it once?

Comment: How do you mean call twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make it a variable,

```
$stylesheet="/css/stylesheet.css";
```

Then I guess you could do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<? echo "$stylesheet?v=",filemtime($stylesheet); ?>">
```

Not sure if that's really any better though.  With what you're doing, you need to use the same filename twice somehow.

Or maybe make a function that you pass the filename to, that returns the string you want to output.  That really only makes sense if you're doing it more than once, though.

Comment: A `,` in a echo statement? i think you wanted a `.` Also short tags must be enabled to use `<?` !

Comment: "Or maybe make a function that you pass the filename to, that returns the string you want to output. That really only makes sense if you're doing it more than once, though." sounds a lot better. Thanks.

Comment: @Rizier123, you're probably correct about the period.  I code in too many languages to keep them all straight.  It's probably Perl that uses the commas.  And I've never had to do anything special on any server I've worked on to get short tags to work.  I've actually never had them not work.  Not on servers I set up, or others' servers.

Answer (score 0):

To include any file in your current file you can also php 
    `<?php include '/css/stylesheet.css' ?>`